# Create sticky component for bottom tab with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**Goal:** Make the `Player Component` stateful when switching between bottom tabs, `Home` and `Settings` in react navigation, using `createBottomTavNavigator`.

I have tried using `Player` component in both `Home` and `Setting` components. But I have a problem with that when I change the text in `Player` screen by clicking the button when I am inside `Home` component and then switch to the `Settings` tab, the text I entered in `Home` screen is not carried over to the `Settings` screen. I guess it is because `Settings` component imports a new `Player` component.

So my question is how to make the `Player` component stateful when switching between those two bottom tabs?

I am kind of hoping to build a player like in `Spotify` app in which the player stays stateful when I am switching between those bottom tabs as shown in the image below.

[image: Spotify stateful player]

Expo snack [here](https://snack.expo.io/r1RKGFnYB)!

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
        <Player />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
        <Player />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Player extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text : 'text'
    }
  }

  changeText = () => {
    this.setState({
      text: 'hello'
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
        <Button
          title="Press"
          onPress={() => this.changeText()}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Settings: { screen: SettingsScreen },
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

**How to reproduce the problem**

**1.** In `Home`, click the `Press` button which will change the text in `Player` component.

**2.** Go the `Settings` tab in the bottom. Now the text you entered in `Home` screen is gone!

Comment: If you solve it can you share it on a snack, please!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tabBarComponent` is all you need:

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator, BottomTabBar } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

const TabBarComponent = props => <BottomTabBar {...props} />;

    const TabScreens = createBottomTabNavigator(
          {
            // other screens
          },
          {
            tabBarComponent: props => (
              <View>
                  <YourPlayerComponent />
                  <TabBarComponent {...props} style={{ borderTopColor: '#605F60' }} />
              </View>
            ),
          }
    );
```

Related here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/pt-BR/bottom-tab-navigator.html

Comment: Can you check this question, please https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/fky3o0/how_to_add_a_fixed_bottom_player/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share